# Gravity forms get SEO title

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravity

I'm trying to get the SEO Meta title of a page that auto fills into a gravity form, so I know which page the form was sent from. I'm using the sabidirectory plugin, but gravity forms will not pick up the page title from:

```
{embed_post:post_title}
```

the code I have put in the functions is:

```
    add_filter('gform_field_value_your_parameter', 'my_custom_population_function');
function my_custom_population_function($value){
    return $showCurrent;
}
```

I need to know how I can pick up the SEO Meta title. I guess I have to change this:

```
return $showCurrent;
```

But don't know what to put here in order to return the SEO Meta title for the form page.

ok got this resolved

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_your_parameter', 'my_custom_population_function');
function my_custom_population_function($value){
global $post;

$parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);

return $parent_title;
}
```

Comment: What is an "SEO Title"?

Comment: Im useing all in one seo pro i wish for it to pick up the seo meta title that i have imputed for that page